# Database connection stops after period of time for no apparent reason

Tags: java, mysql, database, tomcat, jdbc

I deployed my first Java web application a couple of days ago and realized a strange thing was happening. After a period of time all the dynamic content and functionality that relied on a connection to my database (testimonial submission, admin login) stopped working. It seems like this is happening every 24 hours or so. Every morning I realize it isn't working again.

I solve the issue by going in to the Tomcat web application manager and clicking "reload" on the web app in question. Immediately the dynamic features of the website work again.

My server is running `Tomcat` 7 and `MySQL` and the web app uses the `JDBC` driver to establish the connection to the database. I've made no alterations to Apache or Tomcat settings.

I have other web apps written in PHP that work persistently without fault it just seems to be this Java web app that has this problem.

What would cause this to happen and how can I make it so the web app doesn't need to be reloaded before it can establish a database connection again?

EDIT: attached some code for database connection

Database connection

```
public class DBConnection {
    private static Connection conn; 
    private static final Configuration conf     = new Configuration();
    private static final String dbDriver        = conf.getDbDriver();
    private static final String dbHostName      = conf.getDbHostname();
    private static final String dbDatabaseName  = conf.getDbDatabaseName();
    private static final String dbUsername      = conf.getDbUsername();
    private static final String dbPassword      = conf.getDbPassword();

    public Connection getConnection(){
        try{
            Class.forName(dbDriver);
            Connection conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbHostName + dbDatabaseName, dbUsername, dbPassword);
            return conn;
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }
    public void disconnect(){

        try{
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Controller for login form:

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String form         = request.getParameter("form");
// check login details
if(form.equals("loginForm")){
    String username = request.getParameter("username").trim();
    String password = request.getParameter("password").trim();

    password = loginService.hashPassword(password);
    boolean isValidUser = loginService.checkUser(username, password);

    if(isValidUser){

        Cookie loggedIn = new Cookie("loggedIn", "true");
        loggedIn.setMaxAge(60*60*24);
        response.addCookie(loggedIn);

        out.print("success");

    }else{
        out.print("nope");
    }
}
}
```

Login service checks login details are correct:

```
public boolean checkUser(String username, String password){
    boolean isValid = false;
    try{
        sql = "SELECT username, password FROM morleys_user WHERE username=? AND password=? AND isActive=1 LIMIT 1";
        prep = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        prep.setString(1, username);
        prep.setString(2, password);
        rs = prep.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            return true;
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        connection.disconnect();
        }
    return isValid;
}
```

**UPDATE**

If I understand correctly I should not be handling a direct connection to a database and instead be using a service that will manage connections for me.

This is my example of establishing a DataSource connection to a MysQL database.

Establish a new DataSource instance of this class:

```
package uk.co.morleys;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;

public class DataSourceFactory {

    public static DataSource getMySQLDataSource() {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        MysqlDataSource mysqlDS = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream("db.properties");
            props.load(fis);
            mysqlDS = new MysqlDataSource();
            mysqlDS.setURL(props.getProperty("MYSQL_DB_URL"));
            mysqlDS.setUser(props.getProperty("MYSQL_DB_USERNAME"));
            mysqlDS.setPassword(props.getProperty("MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mysqlDS;
    }

}
```

Instantiating a new DataSource for checking user login details

```
public boolean checkUser(String username, String password){
    boolean isValid = false;
    DataSource ds = DataSourceFactory.getMySQLDataSource();
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;

    try{
        con = ds.getConnection();
        sql = "SELECT username, password FROM morleys_user WHERE username=? AND password=? AND isActive=1 LIMIT ";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
        ps.setString(1, username);
        ps.setString(2, password);
        rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){
            return true;
        }

    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        try {
            if(rs != null) rs.close();
            if(ps != null) ps.close();
            if(con != null) con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
    return isValid;
}
```

Comment: do you get any exceptions? post the full stack trace of the exceptions you get.

Comment: How is our `DataSource` configured?

Comment: Can u elaborate the problem and configuration ? MySQL has documentation to use mysql connector j i.e jdbc driver with tomcat  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-tomcat.html.

Comment: I added the JDBC connector and some code for how I log user in, minus the JQUERY ajax.

Comment: This code works fine by the way. The problem is that maybe once per day NO content retrieved from the database is shown and cant login or submit data to database.

Comment: I just wonder if there is a setting on Tomcat that makes the webapp stop communicating with the database every 24 hours or something?

Comment: Could it be something to do with the fact you're setting the cookie maximum age to 24 hours? - I assume that when you reload the web app, the problem goes away because a new cookie is allocated (for another 24 hours.)

Comment: @DavieBrown I expect not as it just expires the cookie, so I just need to login again to see the admin page.

Comment: @MonkeyDLuffy So when I visit the website, even from different IP's there is content of different pages retrieved from the database, user doesn't need to be logged in to view this content. Also users can submit testimonials and admin can login to manage testimonials. . the problem is all this functionality is lost, dynamic content is just white space, I can not login to admin, users can not submit testimonials until I reload the webapp, then it is all fine again, for maybe 24 hours, or maybe less im not sure yet.

Comment: I suggest you use a PooledConnection library so it can keep checking for connectivity and allows you to create multiple connections. Check it out [here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/apidocs/com/mchange/v2/c3p0/ComboPooledDataSource.html)

Comment: you shouldn't create a datasource each time you need a connection. You typically only initiate it once.

Comment: @Pieter How would I re-use the dataSource in different methods once it has been established once?

Comment: A dependency injection framework would be a suitable candidate for doing this but I'll assume you aren't using one. A simple approach would be to create that datasource when initializing your web-app and put it in a public static variable of some class. When you are using a pooled datasource it's important to reuse the same datasource as you'll want to reuse the database connections that the pool manages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that you've never heard of a connection pool before I'm assuming that you not are not very effectively managing database resources. 
The most basic way to access the database is to obtain a connection, execute some statements & close the connection.
In the code you provided I don't see you obtaining or closing a connection, so I assume that you create a single connection when you start your application and keep the connection open "forever". After a certain amount of time your MySql server decides to kill the connection as it's been open for too long.

When you create and close a connection each time you need one, you normally won't encounter any connection timeouts, but you might experience a lot overhead from creating a connection each time your application needs one.

This is where a connection pool comes in; a connection pool manages a number of database connections and your application borrows one each time it needs one. By properly configuring your connection pool the pool will normally transparently take care of broken connections (you might for example configure the pool to renew a connection once it's x minutes/hours old).

You also need to pay attention to resource management; e.g. close a statement as soon as you no longer need it.

The following code demonstrates how your "check user" method can be improved:

```
public boolean checkUser(String username, String password) throws SQLException {
    //acquire a java.sql.DataSource; the DataSource is typically a connection pool that's set-up in the application of obtained via jndi
    DataSource dataSource = acquireDataSource();
    //java 7 try-with-resources statement is used to make sure that resources are properly closed
    //obtain a connection from the pool. Upon closing the connection we return it to the pool
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        //release resources associated with the PreparedStatement as soon as we no longer need it.
        try(PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT username, password FROM morleys_user WHERE username=? AND password=? AND isActive=1 LIMIT 1");){
            ps.setString(1, username);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
            return resultSet.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Common connections pools are [Apache Commons-DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) and [C3P0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/).

As managing sql resources can be quite repetitive and cumbersome you might want to consider using a template: for example [Spring's JdbcTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html)

Example C3p0 configuration:

```
public ComboPooledDataSource dataSource(String driver, String url, String username,String password) throws PropertyVetoException {
    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClass(driver);
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUser(username);
    dataSource.setPassword(password);

    dataSource.setAcquireIncrement(1);
    dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(100);
    dataSource.setMinPoolSize(1);
    dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(1);
    dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(300);
    dataSource.setMaxConnectionAge(36000);

    dataSource.setAcquireRetryAttempts(5);
    dataSource.setAcquireRetryDelay(2000);
    dataSource.setBreakAfterAcquireFailure(false);

    dataSource.setCheckoutTimeout(30000);
    dataSource.setPreferredTestQuery("SELECT 1");
    dataSource.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(60);
    return dataSource;
}//in order to do a "clean" shutdown you should call datasource.close() when shutting down your web app.
```

Comment: I have a couple of questions @Pieter. In my example above I have a class that establishes a connection to the database. I then create an instance of this class in the checkUser method and in several other methods. At the end of these methods I close the connection by calling the disconnect method of each instance of the connection class. If this not actually what is happening? Also in your example above. I think I understand the datasource now, but where would I establish the database connection details, like in my top example I establish the driver, hostname etc?

Comment: Not entirely related but is it correct that the try-with-resources closes the connection and prepared statement for me? and if I want to print a stacktrace of either do I use a catch?

Comment: try-with-resources closes any object that implements the `AutoCloseable` interface. To catch exception just add catch block. examples can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Comment: I'm mostly using the spring framework so I typically declare the DataSource in the spring context and I use dependency injection wherever I need access to it. Where you declare your datasource depends on your project setup. If you are using tomcat then is relatively easy to configure a commons-dbcp connection pool in your tomcat configuration and you can access it in your code via a jndi lookup. You might also declare a datasource as static field somewhere in your own application. I added an example configuration of a C3p0 datasource.

Comment: So if I create a custom class it will only auto close if I make it implement `AutoCloseable`. Otherwise I need a `finally` to close?

Comment: I've never done that as I haven't found the need for it but I guess that it will work.

Answer (score 5):

MySQL times out the connection after some period of time. The standard way to deal with this is to use a properly configured connection pool (with a configured DataSource) instead of using DriverManager directly.

The connection pool will check for and discard "stale" connections.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this "connection pool", something I've not heard of before.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/en/connector-j-usagenotes-j2ee-concepts-connection-pooling.html

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek I updated my question with what I think is a valid solution. Does it look okay to you?

Comment: No, you should not be implementing DataSource - you should be configuring one with a connection pool, and using that. Reading the documentation (try googling "java DataSource" and "java connection pool") would be much more productive than trying to re-invent the wheel.